# pre-process file

Tags: c#

I have a folder in my PC with a lot of musics, and, I want to listing my musics in another PC, whiout get the file for my another PC, in other words, I whant to pre-process the music file and listing in my other PC....

I will develop the server and the client, how is the best way to make this transfer ?

How I can make the pre-process of music file and the client recive the music pre-processed informations and play the music ?

For the IP system, I will use the Hamachi, because I don't have fix IP, or, I have other way to make this connection ?

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: for now, do not develop a code on it, just because I do not know...so I came here to ask, what is the best way to make a code to do this

Comment: @DannyBeckett stop telling people post code, how he post code if he dont know anyhell about it

Comment: @MustafaEkici We expect questions to show research effort. If the OP hasn't shown any research effort (which he hasn't), then we expect people to "try something", then come back when they're stuck, posting relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) on both the server and the client. The server listens for connections and the client connects to the server. As long as you can figure out the IP of the server (e.g. it is fixed, or you have a domain name that always resolves to the correct address) then you can make it work.

Look for ID3 tag libraries to read the metadata from your music files. Then you can send the metadata over and list all your music on the other side.